# Make button coloured in plotly express

Tags: python, button, plotly, visualization, plotly-python

I have the following button in plotly express:

```
fig.update_layout(
    shapes=[vertical_line],
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[
                dict(label="Toggle Shapes",
                     method="relayout",
                     args=[{
                        "shapes": [vertical_line],
                        "annotations":  vline_annotation}],
                     args2=[{
                        "shapes": rectangle_shape + [vertical_line], 
                        "annotations": rectangle_annotation+ vline_annotation}],
                    ),
            ],
        )
    ]
)
```

This button is too bright for the plotly_dark theme, and is thus unreadable. I would like to change the color, however it seems this button doesn't have a parameter to set color in plotly express (to the best of my knowledge). How would I make this button green?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `bgcolor` at the `updatemenus` level (not the `button` level) [(docs)](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/updatemenus/#layout-updatemenus-items-updatemenu-bgcolor):

```py
updatemenus=[
    dict([ 
        type="buttons",
        buttons=[
            #...
        ],
        bgcolor = "#222",
        bordercolor = "#FFF",
        borderwidth = 0.5
    ])
]
```